# In PyTorch, how to convert the cuda() related codes into CPU version?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, gpu

I have some existing PyTorch codes with `cuda()` as below, while `net` is a `MainModel.KitModel` object:

```
net = torch.load(model_path)
net.cuda()
```

and

```
im = cv2.imread(image_path)
im = Variable(torch.from_numpy(im).unsqueeze(0).float().cuda())
```

I want to test the code in a machine without any GPU, so I want to convert the cuda-code into CPU version. I tried to look at some relevant posts regarding the CPU/GPU switch of PyTorch, but they are related to the usage of `device` and thus doesn't apply to my case.

Comment: You can simply use `.cpu()` instead of `.cuda()` or the device variable which moves the tensors based on gpu availability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by kHarshit in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035811/in-pytorch-how-to-convert-the-cuda-related-codes-into-cpu-version#comment109720150_62035811), you can simply replace `.cuda()` call with `.cpu()`:

```py
net.cpu()
# ...
im = torch.from_numpy(im).unsqueeze(0).float().cpu()
```

However, this requires changing the code in multiple places every time you want to move from GPU to CPU and vice versa.

To alleviate this difficulty, pytorch has a more "general" method [`.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to).
You may have a `device` variable defining where you want pytorch to run, this `device` can also be the CPU (!).
for instance:

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
  device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
  device = torch.device("cpu")
```

Once you determined *once* in your code where you want/can run, simply use `.to()` to send your model/variables there:

```py
net.to(device)
# ...
im = torch.from_numpy(im).unsqueeze(0).float().to(device)
```

BTW,
You can use `.to()` to control the data type (`.float()`) as well:

```py
im = torch.from_numpy(im).unsqueeze(0).to(device=device, dtype=torch.float)
```

PS,
Note that the `Variable` API has been [deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated) and is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

```py
   net = torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

Pytorch docs: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-on-cpu-load-on-gpu